# Furring Strips for Floor

Tags: flooring

I need 5/8" furring strips for floor. Should I plane down 3/4" boards or cut strips of 5/8" plywood?

Probably same cost when all is done. Pros and cons?

Comment: Table saw blades are easier to replace them planer knives, and you'll make less mess

Comment: I'd pay a wood shop the plane them down.  But plywood strips does seems the correct approach.

Comment: if the cost is same, which one is less work ?

Answer (score 3):

I love using plywood for furring, it comes in 1/8 increments, you can rip it suit your needs, wide or narrow, and the real biggie, you can put as many nails or screws in it you want, and it will not split like regular 1X material.

1X material, when gotten as furring strips nowadays is an inferior material, IMO, it readily twists and bends, making it difficult to set tight to a surface. Something you really don't need to happen on a floor.

Comment: yeah those strips in the big box store are a sad joke, i've seen shipwreck timber in better shape.